# simulate current date during tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, time

I am writing tests and I wonder if there is a way to change the current date during my test?

The point is that I am testing the statistic functionality of the application, which is connected to a tracking model that creates an instance every time an action is called (only some actions are tracked, via a "before_filter only" call)

So I need to call this actions in different controller at different points in time to test my analytics component is making the right calculations, but I did not find any way to implement change_current_time in the following sample code:

```
test "login count" do
  change_current_time(2.day.ago)
  get "users/login/testuser/testpassword"
  assert login_count(2.day.ago) == 1
  change_current_time(1.day.ago)
  get "users/login/testuser/testpassword"
  get "users/login/testuser1/testpassword1"
  assert login_count(1.day.ago) == 2
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bunch of gems for doing this kind of thing. My favourite is delorean: https://github.com/bebanjo/delorean

Comment: Would give extra kudos for the quote of back to the futur, I love using this gem!

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked a while ago, but there is a solution now that doesn't require and additional gems or installation.

```
time = 2.days.ago
travel_to(time)
```

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this kind of testing is to Mock the method/class you want to test.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

The idea is you can create an identical function, except for passing in a date instead of relying on current date, and test that instead.  The difficulty comes from making sure the two functions really are otherwise equivalent and keeping any changes to them in sync.

There are existing frameworks and such out there for mocking, but I'm not really familiar enough with them to recommend one to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is gem for mocking time in Rails.
 
https://github.com/harvesthq/time-warp

```
time = (2.days.ago)

pretend_now_is(time) do
  get "users/login/testuser/testpassword"
  assert login_count(Date.today) == 1 # it's stubbed
end

time = (1.days.ago)

pretend_now_is(time) do
  get "users/login/testuser/testpassword"
  get "users/login/testuser1/testpassword1"
  assert login_count(Date.today) == 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This gem looks interesting and well-maintained: https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop